Could the product of two Bessel functions of the first kind be expressed in terms of infinite series $J_n(x)J_m(\alpha x)$, where $n,m\in\{0,2\}$?
It is well known that the square of the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero has the Maclaurin series expansion
$$
J_{0}(x)^{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\Gamma(k+\tfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, x^{2k} \, .
$$
I am wondering whether analogous series expansions can also be nicely expressed for other products of Bessel functions of the first kind. I am particularly interested in the products $J_n(x) J_m(\alpha x)$, where $n,m \in \{0, 2\}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

In one sense the answer is trivially "yes": these products will have well-defined Maclaurin series expansions of their own. So the question is really whether the resulting coefficients can be expressed nicely.

@Semiclassical Thanks Mike. Yes, i am looking for some nice form so that I can use it for my further calculations.

Have you tried Cauchy product formula ? Are you sure to consider two consider two different variables $x$ and $y$ ?

@Abezhiko Cauchy product formula is something that is worth trying but only applies when $x=y$. Thanks. Yes, here I am interested in the case when $x \ne y$ necessarily. The case $x=y$ corresponds to the boundary conditions of my problem and is also of some interest.

@Abezhiko Actually here $y=\alpha x$. I have updated the question

The book "A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions" by Watson is always worth a try. I don't know about the particular formula you search for, but there are lots of interesting identities; maybe you find it there

@GhostAmarth ok thanks. I think Cauchy formula seems to work. I get hypergeom functions though

This kind of series exist, even if I wouldn't call them "nice". For example, one finds in Gradstein & Ryzhik :
$$
J_\mu(ax)J_\nu(bx) = \frac{a^\mu b^\nu}{\Gamma(\nu+1)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ka^{2k}}{k!} \frac{F(-k,-\nu-k;\mu-1;b^2/a^2)}{\Gamma(\nu+k+1)} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\mu+\nu+2k},
$$
with $F$ the ordinary hypergeometric function, as well as
$$
J_\mu(x)J_\nu(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{(\mu+\nu+k+1)_k}{\Gamma(\mu+k+1)\Gamma(\nu+k+1)} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\mu+\nu+2k},
$$
where $(\,\cdot\,)_k$ denotes Pochhammer's symbol.

Thanks a lot for the answer

@Siegfriedenberghofen  You're welcome ;)

If you specialize to integer $\mu,\nu$ then the second formula can be expressed as \begin{align}
J_\mu (x)J_\nu(x)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{(2k+\mu+\nu)!}{(k+\mu+\nu)!~(k+\mu)!~(k+\nu)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\mu+\nu+2k}\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \binom{2k+\mu+\nu}{k+\nu}\binom{2k+\mu+\nu}{k}\frac{(x/2)^{2k+\mu+\nu}}{(2k+\mu+\nu)!}
\end{align}
So the coefficients are essentially products of binomial coefficients.

Also, the DLMF links these back to a more general formula on generalized hypergeometric functions: https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.12#E1
